Any differences between workspace dependency and re-export from core library?
I have a mid-sized Rust workspace divided in smaller focused modules, all expanding the core internal library where all the main models and traits are defined
app
lib/
  + core/
  + macros/
  + models/
modules/
  + [etc.]

and the dependency hierarchy goes macros->models->core->[modules]->app
As of now, i have set up the core library to re-export structures from core libraries needed to make the core of the application work (like chrono::{DateTime, Utc} and things like async-trait)
But at the same time, in the cargo.toml i have defined workspace dependencies like log, test-case and tokio in addition to the internal core library references.
Is there any functional difference between re-exporting a dependency shared between multiple projects in a workspace and defining a workspace dependency to inherith from all projects, apart from having to define dependencyname.workspace = true in each project?
As far as i know, the only practical difference is that the re-exports are "children" to the module that exported them

There is little difference beyond the obvious effects on paths (naming of items). Some small effects:

Compiler error messages may sometimes start printing your re-export paths instead of the original library paths.
If one of your packages has a dependency on core that it would not otherwise have, then a rebuild may be slower if both that package and core must be rebuilt, because that package can’t start until the rebuild of core gets to the metadata output stage. (These kinds of timings and dependencies can be captured for review with cargo build --timings.)

